# Googlebot returns with AJAX temporarily unreachable in Meteor Js Application

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I built a Meteor application and installed the spiderable package. I've deployed with Meteor Up smart package. Everything seems to be working fine but in google webmaster tools I only get partial page rendering. I have checked that the `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` is present in the `<head>` 
section.
The site can be seen at http://adjustmentjobs.com

The errors listed by googlebot are as follows: 
https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js  Script  Blocked 
http://adjustmentjobs.com/sockjs/725/ju0i7bzc/xhr_send  AJAX    Not found
http://adjustmentjobs.com/sockjs/068/uat6sjkk/xhr_send  AJAX    Temporarily unreachable 
http://adjustmentjobs.com/sockjs/370/u7hz6996/xhr_send  AJAX    Temporarily unreachable 
http://adjustmentjobs.com/sockjs/info?cb=nqf08z0y_h AJAX    Temporarily unreachable 
http://adjustmentjobs.com/sockjs/info?cb=wqf89krdmo AJAX    Temporarily unreachable

I think the problem might be with phantomjs on the server but I can't determine what exactly the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see `sockjs/info?cb=xxx` as an error, `spiderable` isn't working.

Spiderable is a bit quirky when it comes to debugging. There are some weird issues, so make sure:

- If you use [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) make sure you use a version without the accented characters. Which spiderable is not compatible with (bit odd). Use a compatible package from atmosphere that have these removed.
- If you use ssl check that your certificate isn't being rejected.
- Check that each of your publish methods actually return something, if they return nothing and don't call `this.ready()` then spiderable will time out waiting to render the page.
- Check the page can render on your own computer using a local version of phantomjs (gives out debug errors too). A script that does this can be found on : http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/spiderable/
- Check your server logs for output from phantomjs's `stderr`
- There are a couple of packages on atmospherjs that have forked versions of spiderable that provide a bit more debug info, you could use those to see whats going wrong.
- Check your web page's raw html source to see that the html is actually being rendered by appending `?_escaped_fragment_=#` to the url. You shouldn't expect to see an empty body.

Also looking at your site `http://adjustmentjobs.com/?_escaped_fragment_=#` it looks like all is okay. You might want to check that all pages work.

Also Googlebot will 'test' your site without the `?_escaped_fragment_`, so in this case there will be errors like the above.